# Combine float and absolute position

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-float, absolute

I am creating a calendar where all the events are displayed in a single div. According to the `top` and `height` values, the event should be placed in a determinate place. Let me show you.

In this image, both events at 6am are at the same vertical alignment. I can solve that behavior using [`float: left`<sup>(jsfiddle)</sup>](http://jsfiddle.net/manix/56z1kfj6/2/).
[image]

If events do not have `vertical alignment` conflics (the height and top don't collide) then I can emulate this behavior using [`absolute position`<sup>(jsfiddle)</sup>](http://jsfiddle.net/manix/fvt60mnk/1/) but NOT `float`.
[image]

#### the issue

The real problem comes when I try to place the events at 9am and 9:40am and make them look like the image above. Asume the following properties:

- `9:00` height: 50px, top: 200px
- `9:40` height: 50px, top: 230px
- bottom of `9:00 event`: 200px + 50px = 250px
- top of `9:30 event`: 230px
- Then, they are sharing `20px` (250px - 230px) vertically.

That is why I tried to do something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="event" style="height: 50px; top: 200px; float:left;">9 AM</div>
    <div class="event" style="height: 50px; top: 230px; float:left;">9:40 AM</div>
</div>
```

...but float property does not work in elements with absolute position.

#### Overview

My idea is to treat the `top` value as a guide to place the event vertically in the calendar according to its hour. For example,

- 6am -> top: 100px
- 7am -> top: 150px
- 8pm -> top: 200px

#### Ways to achieve

I tried to solve this by myself using pure ccs, but I do not mind apply javascript. However, I can not show you my attempts with javascript because I do not even can make a considerable css result. As I said before, I am using top property because I thought it could be easy position manipulation, but I could use another method if is necessary. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using relative positioning *almost* solves your issue.  However, it leaves gaps between events:

### Fiddle #1

The only way I know to solve this problem is using absolute positioning, with JavaScript determining `top` and `left` coordinates:

```
var events= [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.container div')),
                //array of event elements. See http://davidwalsh.name/nodelist-array
    count= [],  //running total of events during an hour. used to calculate left offset.
    i,          //loop through the events
    time,       //event time as array, such as ['6','AM']
    hour,       //event hour (1 - 24)
    minute,     //event minute (0 - 59)
    offset;     //top offset based on hour and minute

events.sort(function(a,b) {
  return a.textContent < b.textContent ? -1 : 1;
});

for(i = 0 ; i < events.length ; i++) {
  time= events[i].textContent.split(' ');
  hour= time[0].split(':')[0] * 1;
  if(time[1]==='PM' && hour !== 12) {
    hour+= 12;
  }
  minute= time[0].split(':')[1] || 0;
  offset= hour+minute/60;
  count[hour]= (count[hour] || 0)+1;
  events[i].style.top= (offset-6)*50 + 'px';
  events[i].style.left= count[hour]*100-100 + 'px';
}
```

### Fiddle #2

Note that this code needs some tweaking to avoid events covering up other events, as you'll in the Fiddle for 12:00 PM.

Comment: Rick, your code has a lot of sense. Could you  rename the javascript vars and comment it a little bit? I want to understand and try to improving your code by my side because it looks very good to apply

Comment: Ha, my code does tend to be terse, especially if I'm programming in the middle of the night.  Apologies for that.  I've updated my answer, plus I've added a sort procedure to ensure the content always appears the same regardless of order.

Answer (score 3):

You should add positioning to your divs. If you add `position:relative` to your classes you will be able to use `top:xxpx` to offset the vertical position. I think you will need to think about a lot of edge cases that might make a pure css solution difficult, but thought this might at least help.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/markm/qvevedva/

Comment: Actually use `relative` fix the structure a lot :D. But as you said, need to do a very huge work to fill the edges.

Answer (score 0):

What if you use `margin-top` instead of `top`, does it work for you?  You might be able to get this result:

[image]

You might also need to create a container `div` for every hour and include the underlying event divs in there:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="event" style="height: 50px;">6AM</div>
   <div class="event" style=" height: 50px;">6AM</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
   <div class="event" style="height: 50px;">9 AM</div>
   <div class="event" style="height: 50px; margin-top: 25px;">9:30 AM</div>
   <div class="event" style="height: 50px; margin-top: 33px;">9:40 AM</div>
</div>
```

Here is some [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/56z1kfj6/4/) code on JSFiddle for reference.

Comment: The problem using margin is that each element is relative to the closest element and easily break the schema.